# is there a facebook user login framework for gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook

I want to enable someone login using facebook,

Is there a framework that you have used to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, I gave an answer to a similar question just a couple of hours ago.  Please use Rpx, which requires minimal work from your part.

[how to make it easy for users to register at my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900877/how-to-make-it-easy-for-users-to-register-at-my-site/2900932#2900932)

Comment: This also what was suggested last time zjm1126 asked the question too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886736/any-gae-framework-for-facebook-user-login-closed